# Como mantener los menus laterales siempre arriba en foundation

Tags: html5, css3, foundation

Lo que busco es que el menu, al momento de estar en moviles no scrolléy se mantenga, lo cual lo hace, pero al momento de darle click a los menus laterales, sube el tab-bar, alguien sabe que hacer para que se mantenga siempre arriba?

```
<head>
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Hola</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css" />
    <script src="js/modernizr.js"></script>
    <script src="js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/login_function.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="alerts/lib/alertify.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="alerts/lib/alertas.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="alerts/themes/alertify.core.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="alerts/themes/alertify.default.css" />

<body class="<?php echo $page ?>">

    <div class="off-canvas-wrap" data-offcanvas>
        <div class="inner-wrap">
            <!--
            <!-- Nav bar responsive -->
    <div class="fixed">
            <nav class="tab-bar hidden-for-medium-up">
                <section class="left-small">
                    <a class="left-off-canvas-toggle menu-icon" href="#"><span></span></a>
                </section>

                <section class="middle tab-bar-section">
                    <h1 class="title"><a href="index.php"><img src="img/logo-responsive.png"></a></h1>
                </section>

                <section class="right-small">
                    <a class="right-off-canvas-toggle menu-icon" href="#"><span></span></a>
                </section>
            </nav>
    </div>  
            <!-- Nav bar desktop-->
    <div class="fixed">
        <nav class="top-bar show-for-medium-up" data-topbar role="navigation">
        <ul class="title-area">
            <li class="name">

            </li>
        <!-- Remove the class "menu-icon" to get rid of menu icon. Take out "Menu" to just have icon alone -->
            <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span>Menu</span></a></li>
        </ul>

        <section class="top-bar-section">
        <!-- Right Nav Section -->
        <ul class="left">
            <li style="margin-left:15px;">
                 <a href="index.php">
                    <img src="img/hola.png">
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="right">
        <li><a class="sesion" href="login.php">INICIAR SESIÓN</a></li>
        </ul>
        <br>
        <ul class="right nav-menu">
        <li><a href="servicios.php">SERVICIOS</a></li>
        </ul>

        <!-- Left Nav Section 
        <ul class="left">
        <li><a href="#">Left Nav Button</a></li>
        </ul>
        </section>-->
        </nav>
</div>  
        <!-- Offcanvas menu -->

        <aside class="left-off-canvas-menu">
        <ul class="off-canvas-list">
            <li><label>MENÚ</label></li>
            <li><a href="index.php">Inicio</a></li>
            <li><a href="servicios.php">Servicios</a></li>
        </ul>
        </aside>

        <aside class="right-off-canvas-menu">
        <ul class="off-canvas-list">
            <li><label>MENÚ</label></li>
            <li><a href="login.php">Iniciar sesión</a></li>
        </ul>
        </aside>

        <section class="main-section">    

        <a class="exit-off-canvas"></a>
```

Comment: Por favor, crea un [mcve] para que podamos ver el problema

Answer (score 0):

me parece que esto se matine con una propiedad en css que se llama 
Position :fixed.

Aquí tienes una gran explicación.

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_fixed_menu.asp

Comment: Cuando se coloca un enlace a material externo debe incluir las partes relevantes en la respuesta, dado el caso de que el enlace deje de funcionar.